# Load Multiple Cores in Banana which are created in Datastax Solr

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, banana

I want to load multiple cores which are created in Datastax Cassandra Solr.

Objective is to create various Banana dashboards & provide to users on per Core basis.

Currently I am able to do it by changing:

```
$DSE_HOME/resources/banana/src/config.js
solr_core: "MY_OWN_CORE"
```

Is this possible to load multiple cores by giving list in above property? 
Or what should be the best way for all Cassandra Tables/Solr Cores to have an individual Dashboard.

Currently I have followed [this link](https://medium.com/@carolinerg/visualizing-cassandra-solr-data-with-banana-b54bf9dd24c) to enable Banana in DSE & to load 1 Solr Core.

Current Version of DSE, I am using is DSE 5.0.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem solved with below steps: I need to give below:

```
$DSE_HOME/resources/banana/src/config.js
solr_core: "MY_OWN_CORE"
```

Still I can change or load another core from Banana UI.

1) Clone https://github.com/LucidWorks/banana to $DSE_HOME/resources/banana.

Make sure you've checked out the release branch (should be the default).
If you want, you can rm -rf .git at this point to save space, but it's not very big anyway.

2) Edit resources/banana/src/config.js and:

change solr_core to the core you're most frequently going to work with (only a convenience, you can pick a different one later on the settings for each dashboard.
change banana_index to banana.dashboards (**can be anything you want, but modify step 3 accordingly**). Not strictly necessary if you don't want to save dashboards to solr.

3) Post the banana schema from resources/banana/resources/banana-int-solr-4.5/banana-int/conf

Use the solrconfig.xml from wikipedia demo instead of the one provided by banana
Recommend calling the core banana.dashboards.

Not strictly necessary if you don't want to save dashboards to solr.

```
curl --data-binary @solrconfig.xml -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8' "http://localhost:8983/solr/resource/banana.dashboards/solrconfig.xml"

curl --data-binary @schema.xml -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8' "http://localhost:8983/solr/resource/banana.dashboards/schema.xml"

curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8' "http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=banana.dashboards"
```

4) Edit resources/tomcat/conf/server.xml and add the following inside the  tags:

5) If you've previously started DSE, remove resources/tomcat/work.

6) Start DSE in Solr mode, and go to http://localhost:8983/banana

Answer (score 1):

The best way might be to have multiple instances of your banana directory, one per search core under `$DSE_HOME/resources`

Comment: this means i need to create multiple banana directories under resources folder? If yes then what would be url to access that banana interface. Current interface can be accessible at http://localhost:8983/banana